# How to move GPG key to a different host? Errors on import

Tags: gpg

I am trying to move my GPG configuration from home to work PC. This is how I exported my keys:

```
sms@home-sms:~/Public$ gpg --list-keys
/home/sms/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
----------------------------
pub   rsa3072 2023-07-17 [SC]
      56D61B8B83BD3E534477DE20061D81ADCE33F311
uid           [ultimate] Szymon M. Sabat <capt_sms@protonmail.com>
sub   rsa3072 2023-07-17 [E]
sms@home-sms:~/Public$ gpg --list-secret-keys
/home/sms/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
----------------------------
sec   rsa3072 2023-07-17 [SC]
      56D61B8B83BD3E534477DE20061D81ADCE33F311
uid           [ultimate] Szymon M. Sabat <capt_sms@protonmail.com>
ssb   rsa3072 2023-07-17 [E]

sms@home-sms:~/Public$ gpg -a --export >pub.asc
sms@home-sms:~/Public$ cat pub.asc 
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
[key]
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
sms@home-sms:~/Public$ gpg -a --export-secret-keys >sec.asc
sms@home-sms:~/Public$ cat sec.asc 
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
[key]
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
sms@home-sms:~/Public$ ls
pub.asc  sec.asc
```

Then I've copied the `asc` files to my other machine and when imporing the secret key (public key was imported w/o problems), I got errors:

```
sms@ubudev-sms:~/Admin$ gpg --list-keys
gpg: directory '/home/sms/.gnupg' created
gpg: keybox '/home/sms/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: /home/sms/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
sms@ubudev-sms:~/Admin$ gpg --list-secret-keys
sms@ubudev-sms:~/Admin$ ls
packages.microsoft.gpg  pub.asc  sec.asc
sms@ubudev-sms:~/Admin$ gpg --import pub.asc 
gpg: key 061D81ADCE33F311: public key "Szymon M. Sabat <capt_sms@protonmail.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
sms@ubudev-sms:~/Admin$ gpg --import sec.asc 
gpg: key 061D81ADCE33F311: "Szymon M. Sabat <capt_sms@protonmail.com>" not changed
gpg: key 061D81ADCE33F311/061D81ADCE33F311: error sending to agent: No such file or directory
gpg: error building skey array: No such file or directory
gpg: error reading 'sec.asc': No such file or directory
gpg: import from 'sec.asc' failed: No such file or directory
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg:              unchanged: 1
gpg:       secret keys read: 1
```

Instructions seemed simple, what did I do wrong?

Comment: I would suggest to list your secret keys on both machines and compare the results.  Could be an issue with the gpg-agent, not the imported keys.  And maybe run the import in `--verbose` mode.

Comment: Or gpg on the target machine is missing a directory, see https://security.stackexchange.com/a/270781

Comment: Or yet another possible issue: different version of gpg between the to machines, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51134594

Comment: @markgraf needed dirs were created automatically when I created new key, but they weren't on import. Thank you! If u write an answer, I'll accept

Comment: No need, but please give an upvote to the "missing directory" solution mentionned in the comment above.